# TSLint tells my identifier is never reassigned, but it's changeable somehow

Tags: angular, typescript

What should I do? The method is work either I use `let` or `const`.

As you can see at the image below, the variable is binded with my input element and used multiple times due to iteration.

(Does two-way binding is described as `const`/`let` when its value change / you can change its value?).

[image: This is the full method]

And here is the linter say:

`Identifier 'electronic' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'. (prefer-const)`

Comment: Why can't you just use `const`? It's right.

Comment: I'm concerned about which one is right. Because the value of that `electronic` or `quantity` or `wattage` is binded with two-way binding, binded with my `<input>` forms.
In the other word, you can change its value.
Which doesn't make any sense when it comes to `const` where you can't change its value.

Comment: Using `const` would just make it so the `electronic` variable can't be reassigned. It doesn't say anything about the object the variable is referencing. It doesn't effect anything outside of the loop.

Comment: `const` doesn't make the object immutable. It makes the reference to the object immutable.

Comment: should I use `const` then?
But I'm not satisfied yet because I can reassign a constant like `const foo = 1; foo = 2;`, and the compiler doesn't even care (No exception in the console). But it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable".

Comment: But I'm not. I declare the `const` inside `ngOnInit()`. Yes the linter said: can't  reassign to const. But the console says nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues in understanding the technologies:

1. TSLint has no idea about your 2 way binding, so it inform you about the missing reassignment
2. Your variable exist only inside of this for-loop, so using **const** there would be completely fine since you did not plan to modify the value during one iteration

Comment: I see, so the answer is:
- You can use `const` when there is no value changed during one iteration.
- The `const` inside that iteration only behave as a temporary (As mentioned being inside an iteration).

Am I right?

Comment: yes, your variable is forgotten outside of that for-loop